# Unable do define a simple controller in AngularJS 1.3.0-rc.4

Tags: angularjs

This works in angularJS 1.2.0. I want to be able to define a simple controller this way.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='' ng-controller='ctrl'>
<input type="text" ng-model="data.input"><br>
{{data.input}}
<script>
function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = {input:'hejsan'}
}
</script> 
</div>
```

[Demo](http://www.jsexample.com/#DwZwxgTglgDgLgAhBMBeARACznGAuAegIEMArYgDwDoBzAezpoBsBTYmKEKsOgWxPIUCTKACMQJAHY0Ark2IRSEgIxUATFQAMU2fIhVeUSVSXoAfMALho8MwChgAEygA3BNIC07GKgDkv9xoPHkk4CDomVgg/MDCmX3tgIxgZRDgATxgWDDgWCjh0QI9eOkcWJgxHYjhiKmTU82BRCHsAb1aqmrrJFLgAXz6Ha1g4ewAzGUlYqDpJBFiIJgAKABJwOiyASgRWuwR9hDWeLKpO4gRUHfq4PF9MFiViSV9Bwcth2wQHAmcXMyA)

However, in 1.3.0-rc.4 it doesn't work. Why can't I define a controller this way?

[Demo 1.3.0-rc.4](http://www.jsexample.com/#DwZwxgTglgDgLgAhBMBeARACznGAuAegIEMArYgDwDoBzAezpoBsBTYmKEKsOgWxPIUCTKACMQJAHY0Ark2IRSEgIxUAzFQAMAWhRUALFNnyIVXlElUl6AHzAC4aPBsAoYABMoANwTTt7GFQAciDfGm0eSTgIOiZWCGCwaKYg12ALGBlEOABPGBYMOBYKOHQw7V46dxYmDHdiOGIqDKzbYFEIVwBvLvrG5slMuABfYbdHWDhXADMZSSSoOkkEJIgmAAoAEnA6fIBKBC6XBBOEbZ58qj7iBFRDlrg8IMwWJWJJILGx+wnnBDcCJ4vDYgA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Angular v1.3.0-beta defining controller constructors in the global scope is **[no longer supported](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3f2232b5a181512fac23775b1df4a6ebda67d018)**.